# Acomodar icono en un extremo

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap-4

Como ven en la siguiente imagen, tengo un ítem "computadora" y ese "+"; necesito que este lo más pegado a  la derecha posible; esto es un fragmento de un sidebar y necesito que todos los "+" queden iguales.

[image: fragmento del sidebar]

A continuación les pongo el código de este fragmento:

```
<div class="card sidebar">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
            <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    Computadoras&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                </button>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body">
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li class="list-group-item item tres List"><a class="nav-linkSidebar" id="nav-notebook-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-notebook" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-notebook" aria-selected="false">Notebook</a></li>
                    <li class="list-group-item item tres List"><a class="nav-linkSidebar" id="nav-pc-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-pc" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-pc" aria-selected="false">PC's Armadas</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Si para las recomendaciones es necesarios sacar los &nbsp ; entonces no hay problema. Pero necesito moverlos.

[image: ejemplo]

la imagen verde es un ejemplo de lo que necesito hacer!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Por favor intenta este código:

```
<div class="card sidebar">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
          
            <div class="mb-0">
                <span style="float: left; line-height: 35px">Computadoras</span><button style="float: right" class="btn text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body">
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li class="list-group-item item tres List"><a class="nav-linkSidebar" id="nav-notebook-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-notebook" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-notebook" aria-selected="false">Notebook</a></li>
                    <li class="list-group-item item tres List"><a class="nav-linkSidebar" id="nav-pc-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-pc" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-pc" aria-selected="false">PC's Armadas</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

#### Explicación ☕:

Modifiqué el elemento button para que flotara hacia la derecha utilizando el atributo style="" en el elemento.

Comment: hola! no es lo que necesito...yo solo necesito mover el símbolo "+"; a la derecha y esto que me sugeriste me movió todo el texto también

Comment: Lo he editado tal como me lo pediste, espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: casi pero no...por mas que ponga h6 en vez de h2 no queda...

Comment: muchas gracias!! ahora si ajusto un poco el css pero se logro lo que quería!!

Comment: Es una mala práctica utilizar estilos in-line. Usa las clases propias del framework

Comment: Si pero era para dar una idea de lo que queria hacer...

Answer (score 3):

Ya que estás con bootstrap te doy una solución con este framework

```
<div class="card sidebar">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
            <h2 class="mb-0 " style="">
                <button class="btn d-flex justify-content-between w-25" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo"  >
                <span>Computadoras</span>
                <span><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                </button>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body">
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li class="list-group-item item tres List"><a class="nav-linkSidebar" id="nav-notebook-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-notebook" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-notebook" aria-selected="false">Notebook</a></li>
                    <li class="list-group-item item tres List"><a class="nav-linkSidebar" id="nav-pc-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-pc" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-pc" aria-selected="false">PC's Armadas</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

He puesto el botón en display flex. El título del botón lo he colocado en un span, ahora el d-flex junto a justify-content-between mantiene cada parte en un extremo.
He quitdo el text-align.
Para que ves que funciona le dado un ancho al botón con la clase w-25.
En general las alineaciones se solventan bastante bien con el modelo flex-box.

Answer (score 0):

1 creamos una estructura de iconos para eso, creamos una clase "icon" y le  asignamos el pseudoelemento ::after (después) y usamos la propiedad font-family para indicar el tipo de fuente, en tu caso FontAwesome, como valor colocas 'Font Awesome 5 Free'.

```
.icon::after {
font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
font-weight: 900;}
```

2 creamos los iconos de la siguiente forma "nombredeicon::after" y asignamos la propiedad content y como valor colocamos el identificador del icono.

```
.icon-plus::after {
content: "\f067";}
```

3 modificamos la clase btn de Bootstrap agregando la propiedad "position" y le asignamos el valor "relative". Por que ? por que de esta forma evitamos que el icono se salga del contenedor (btn).

```
.btn {position: relative;}
```

4 tenemos que hacer que el icono se posicione lo mas a la derecha posible, eso lo logramos con "padding-left", "margin-left" o con "position: absolute" junto con "right: 0", de la siguiente forma

```
#headingTwo .icon-plus::after {
padding-left: 15px;}
```

o

```
#headingTwo .icon-plus::after {
margin-left: 15px;}
```

Nota: si optas por la opción de padding o margin no es necesario que modifiques la clase .btn de Bootstrap.

```
#headingTwo .icon-plus::after {
position: absolute;
right: 0;}
```

y por ultimo indicamos el ancho de la siguiente forma

```
#headingTwo .btn {
min-width: 180px;}
```

Nota: para que el icono no este tan pegado al borde modifica el valor de right de 0 a 15px por ejemplo. Si quieres hacerlo como lo muestra la imagen esta debería ser la forma.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar un `span` para eso.

Para que el span dé a la derecha, usaremos CSS:

```
button {
    position: relative;
}

button span {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Teniendo en cuenta que `button` es un contenedor, estamos en la libertad de usar `position: relative`.
Puedes hacerle algunas modificaciones si lo necesitas.